# How to find a Gstreamer bottleneck?

Tags: gstreamer

I have a glvideomixer sink that shows 16 720p-60Hz videos simultaneously in a 4x4 matrix array. When the source of all 16 videos are from 16 different "h264 main profile" files all runs smoothly, but when I acquire the videos from 4 grabber cards (4 x 4HDMI input ports set to 1280x720-60Hz, same as video files) the output gets stutter.

The pipeline is very simple:

```
glvideomixer(name=vmix)
ksvideosrc(device-index=0...15)->capsfilter(video/x-raw,format=YV12,framerate=60/1,height=720,width=1280)->vmix.sink_0...15
```

Note: The ksvideosrc element is only available on Windows platform.

AFAIK the pipeline is GL based, so all the videos streams are implicitly uploaded to an GL context, when the glvideomixer treats them as GL textures. I am right?

But i don't understand why when i use 16 video files all runs smoothly, even when, in theory, the process is more complex because the computer must decode these streams before sending them to the GPU, and when i use the grabber cards, all output is stuttered.

I'm pretty sure that the stream format of the cards are RAW YV12, because i set the capsfilter element to explicitly choose that stream. Here the link to the grabbers: http://www.yuan.com.tw/en/products/capture/capture_sc510n4_hdmi_spec.htm

I think that the bottleneck is there in the PCIe bus, but i not sure because the GPU is an AMD FirePro W7100 run at 16x and the 4 grabber cards are 4x PCIe runs at 4x.

It should be noted that all run smoothly up to 13 video signals from the grabbers. Adding one more the stutter shows up.

So: how to know where is the bottleneck?

Many thanks in advance.

Edit:

The rig is:

- MB: Asus x99-deluxe USB 3.1:
  http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/X99DELUXEU31/
- CPU: Hexacore i7-5930K Haswell 40 PCIe lanes:
  http://ark.intel.com/es/products/82931/Intel-Core-i7-5930K-Processor-15M-Cache-up-to-3_70-GHz
- RAM: Kingston Hyperx PC4 21300 HX426C15FBK2/8 dual channel setup:
  http://www.kingston.com/dataSheets/HX426C15FBK2_8.pdf
- GPU: AMd FirePro W7100 8Gb GDDR5 256 bits:
  http://www.amd.com/en-us/products/graphics/workstation/firepro-3d/7100
- HDD: Kingston SSD Now V300:
  http://www.kingston.com/datasheets/sv300s3_en.pdf

Comment: If you adjust the framerate down to 30 or decrease the resolution does your pipeline work?

Comment: Yes, it work if i set the caps between the ksvideosrc and the mixer sink. And as i said, the pipeline work flawlessly if i use source files instead of the grabbers.

I cannot reduce the FPS nor resolution because is an explicit requirement. Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm, it sure would be interesting if you're actually hitting hardware limits.  What is the motherboard?  I've heard the Skylake motherboards are supposed to be able to move more data.  What is the final requirement for how these get output?  Will they be shown at native resolution?

Comment: The rig is:
- MB: Asus x99-deluxe USB 3.1: https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/X99DELUXEU31/
- CPU: Hexacore i7-5930K Haswell 40 PCIe lanes: http://ark.intel.com/es/products/82931/Intel-Core-i7-5930K-Processor-15M-Cache-up-to-3_70-GHz
- RAM: Kingston Hyperx PC4 21300 HX426C15FBK2/8 dual channel setup: http://www.kingston.com/dataSheets/HX426C15FBK2_8.pdf
- GPU: AMd FirePro W7100 8Gb GDDR5 256 bits: http://www.amd.com/en-us/products/graphics/workstation/firepro-3d/7100
- HDD: Kingston SSD Now V300: http://www.kingston.com/datasheets/sv300s3_en.pdf

Comment: The total resolution of the glvideomixer is 3840x2160, so every video shown on the array have 960x540 pixels. For this reason i have a software videoscaler filter that convert every signal aquired by grabbers from HD to 960x540, and then uploaded to GL context. This software filter is used in both pipelines: The one from files and the other one from grabbers. The first one uses only 20% of CPU to decode and downscale all the 16 videos files, meanwhile the GPU reach the 80% of usage to display the composite 4k final image.

As i said: The first one runs smoothly and the second one gets stutter.

Comment: OK here's a simple test we can use to determine if it's a PCI issue: take all sixteen streams and just output them to your desktop at 1280x720--unchanged.  If that runs fine, then we need you to use GST_DEBUG_DUMP_DOT_DIR or paste more detail on your pipeline.  Could just be some missing queue elements or parameters.